# "Off hand" as a synonym for "nondominant hand"

Tags: phrase-usage

I heard someone in a video using the phrase "off hand" when referring to the left hand of a right-handed person.

Is this a common thing to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In fact, at least in AmE, it is probably *more* common than "non-dominant hand".  "Off-hand" is also significantly older than "non-dominant hand", having been in use for centuries, as opposed to "non-dominant hand" which has really only been in general use for the last 50 years or so, with the first known use being in 1940

Comment: @Moha I've never heard that.

Comment: That's really interesting, because this is the first I'm hearing of that usage.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you You've never heard of "off-hand" for you non-dominant hand?

Comment: Not in my life. I'm probably just remarkably ignorant, happens to the best, but "non-dominant" is definitely more common where I'm from.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you  " I'm probably just remarkably ignorant, happens to the best" Eh, everyone's got gaps in their knowledge that seem weird to someone else.

Comment: I've never heard it and can't find any online dictionary definition including that meaning for _off_, only _off side_ (as opposed to _near side_ ) which means the right side!

Comment: @KateBunting https://www.reddit.com/r/drawing/comments/93955g/offhand_vs_dominant_hand/
https://www.bladeforums.com/threads/question-knife-position-dominant-hand-or-off-hand.206957/  
https://news.psu.edu/story/141241/2006/02/20/research/probing-question-can-you-change-handedness-you-were-born